# Insert SUM combine into select with other column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have problem with my sum function in sql, which is like this:

```
SELECT Member.Name, Book.Title AS BookBought, Order_Member_Det.Quantity, Order_Member_Det.Price, Order_Member.Total
FROM Order_Member
INNER JOIN OrderWithMember ON Order_Member.OrderID = OrderWithMember.OrderID
INNER JOIN Order_Member_Det ON OrderWithMember.MemberOrderID = Order_Member_Det.MemberOrderID
INNER JOIN Member ON OrderWithMember.MemberID = Member.MemberID
INNER JOIN Book ON Order_Member_Det.BookID = Book.BookID
```

And the result is:

```
Name    BookBought           Quantity Price Total
----------------------------------------------------
John    Flip it                 2     50    150
John    California Penal Code   1     50    150
Jack    Forum Internationale    2     80    160
Alice   Securitization          2     80    210
Alice   The Cervical Spine      1     50    210
Kevin   Trading Commodities     1     55    55
James   Aerodynamics            1     90    90
```

I want to add SUM of all total in the table by using SUM(TOTAL) like this:

```
SELECT Member.Name, Book.Title AS BookBought, Order_Member_Det.Quantity, Order_Member_Det.Price, Order_Member.Total, **SUM(Order_Member.Total)**
FROM Order_Member
INNER JOIN OrderWithMember ON Order_Member.OrderID = OrderWithMember.OrderID
INNER JOIN Order_Member_Det ON OrderWithMember.MemberOrderID = Order_Member_Det.MemberOrderID
INNER JOIN Member ON OrderWithMember.MemberID = Member.MemberID
INNER JOIN Book ON Order_Member_Det.BookID = Book.BookID
```

But then I get an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 264
>   Column 'Member.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But If I create new select with just sum like this it works:

```
SELECT SUM(Total) From Order_Member;
```

It works producing this output:

```
ColumnName
665
```

So how can I combine two select in the given, I also used INNER JOIN so subquery might not work here. Any ideas?

Comment: "Msg 8120" is a SQL Server error, not a MySQL error.  I fixed the tag, because the error message is pretty convincing evidence on the database being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as well (not tested)

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT Member.Name, Book.Title AS BookBought, 
        Order_Member_Det.Quantity, Order_Member_Det.Price, Order_Member.Total
    FROM Order_Member
    INNER JOIN OrderWithMember ON Order_Member.OrderID = OrderWithMember.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Order_Member_Det ON OrderWithMember.MemberOrderID = Order_Member_Det.MemberOrderID
    INNER JOIN Member ON OrderWithMember.MemberID = Member.MemberID
    INNER JOIN Book ON Order_Member_Det.BookID = Book.BookID
)
select *, (select sum(total) from cte) as SumTotal
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do this using a window function:

```
SELECT m.Name, b.Title AS BookBought, omd.Quantity, omd.Price, om.Total,
       SUM(Order_Member.Total) OVER (PARTITION BY m.MemberId) as MemberTotal
FROM Order_Member om INNER JOIN
     OrderWithMember owm
     ON om.OrderID = owm.OrderID INNER JOIN
     Order_Member_Det omd
     ON owm.MemberOrderID = omd.MemberOrderID INNER JOIN
     Member m
     ON owm.MemberID = m.MemberID INNER JOIN
     Book b
     ON omd.BookID = b.BookID;
```